# How to add activity indicator to SpriteKit scene

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am trying to add UIActivityIndicatorView to SpriteKit scene as follows:

```
_activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

[_worldNode addChild:_activityIndicator];
```

However this won't work (incompatible pointer type UIActivityIndicatorView* to SKNode* )

I could not find built-in sprite activity indicator. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_worldNode` is `SKNode`, you can't add `UIView` to `SKNode`. Try to add it to `SKView` instead:

```
_activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
_activityIndicator.center = ....
[_worldNode.scene.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];
```

Also make sure `_worldNode.scene` is not `nil` and `_worldNode.scene.view` is not `nil`

Comment: I was looking for SK alternative, so it's easier to manipulate and control. _activityIndicator does not have a position argument.

Comment: Use `center` instead of `position`.

Comment: Works great, too bad there is no way to refer it as a node. Thanks!

Comment: You can create your own `SKSpriteNode` with animation, which looks just like default `UIActivityIndicator`